# oracle insert (group functions are not allowed)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am supposed to write a result table with number of rows in other tables
the result table is simple

```
Create Table result(name varchar2(20), row_table1 number, row_table2 number );
```

but when i insert ussing

```
insert into result values('test',  count(*) from table1,  count(*) from table2);
```

gives an error group functions are not allowed here....

is there any other solution

Comment: Despite the answers, below, may I ask why you would want to do this?

Comment: `count(*)` should have a `select` in front of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the full select statements to it:

```
insert into result 
values(
    'test',  
    (select count(*) from table1),  
    (select count(*) from table2)
);
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9a896/2)

Answer (score 1):

count(*) is not a literal, it's the result of a select:

```
insert into result values('test', (select count(*) from table1),  (select count(*) from table2));
```